# MySQL: How can I get min value from table with duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql

I have table with folowing structure. The content in this table is duplicate. I want to show the record with min price.

```
GROUP  IDX  NAME       PRICE

141003  6   0285-00    499.88000
141003  2   028500     519.13000
141003  1   0285-00    424.12000
141005  2   02851      559.13000
141005  1   0285-1     434.12000
```

**RESULT TABLE**

```
141003  1   0285-00    424.12000
141005  1   0285-1     434.12000
```

I trying this but returned result is:

```
141003  6   0285-00    499.88000
```

Query:

```
select group, idx, name, price
                FROM table
                GROUP BY group
                ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_min.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT group, idx, name, price
    FROM table
    WHERE group = 141003
    ORDER BY price ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: I changed table, added more group, and changed the result table. This query returned correcty result for group 141003

Comment: So are you implying that my answer is correct? Please set my answer as correct in that case, if you are still having problems, please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following query if you want to know the minimum price in each group:

```
select `group`, `idx`, `name`, MIN(price) AS min_price
                FROM `table`
                GROUP BY `group`;
```

[Documentation for 'MIN' function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min)

Answer (score 0):

First of all group is a reserved word in MySQL. You should use ` around it or rename the table. Like this:

```
select `group`, idx, name, price from test_2 where `group` = 141003 order by price desc limit 1;
```

Why do you want to do group by if the group is in the the where condition with one value? Do you want the cheapest item from all the groups?